# How can I declare media queries inside styled components as an object to assign to style?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a styles.jsx file with styled components design. I declared a const this way

```
const InputStyle = {
  maxWidth: '600px',
  marginBottom: '20px',
  '@media(max-width: 740px)': {
    width: '203px',
    marginBottom: '14px',
    backgroundColor: red,
  },
};
```

maxWidth and marginBottom does work but when you go to the screen size specified in the media query, no changes are registered.

And I use this in the screen this way:

```
<Input
          level="first"
          type="text"
          name="fullName"
          style={InputStyle}
          value={formFields.fullName.value}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
```

How can I correctly declare the media query so it works?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `styled-media-queries` pkg like below:

```
import styled from "styled-components"; // You need this as well
import media from "styled-media-query";

const Box = styled.div`
  background: black;

  ${media.lessThan("medium")`
    /* screen width is less than 768px (medium) */
    background: red;
  `}

  ${media.between("medium", "large")`
    /* screen width is between 768px (medium) and 1170px (large) */
    background: green;
  `}

  ${media.greaterThan("large")`
    /* screen width is greater than 1170px (large) */
    background: blue;
  `}
`;
```

doc is available [here](https://github.com/morajabi/styled-media-query)

if you want more complex views to create with media queries you can create components like

```
<DesktopSize /> 
<TabletSize /> 
<MobileSize/>
<WhateverSize />
```

and export them in their own modules and  import an use it the what ever component you want like

```
<TabletSize>
  <Header /> 
  <Slider /> 
  <OtherComponent /> 
</TabletSize>
```

by this way you create your layouts and they are usable throughout of whole app

Comment: This is not what I am looking for exactly, I need it to be a const variable that I can use any where and not only in one styled-component